# How could I get a descending OrderedDict from namedtuple, Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

I know that `somenamedtuple._asdict()` returns a **ascending** `OrderedDict`.

How do I get a **descending** `OrderedDict`?

Comment: Why not just `reversed` it (and wrap it back up in a new `OrderedDict`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the most memory efficient way, do not construct the forward dict in the first place.  That is an unnecessary middleman.

Reverse the fields on the tuple directly:

```
OrderedDict(zip(reversed(somenamedtuple._fields), reversed(somenamedtuple)))
```

Comment: Beat me to it (`dict(zip(*map(reversed, (t._fields, t))))`)!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reversed()` to get a reversed OrderedDict from the namedtuple like:

#### Code:

```
OrderedDict(reversed(list(x._asdict().items())))
```

#### Test Code:

```
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

MyTuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', 'f1 f2')

x = MyTuple(1, 2)

print(OrderedDict(reversed(list(x._asdict().items()))))
```

#### Results:

```
OrderedDict([('f2', 2), ('f1', 1)])
```

Comment: Note: As of 3.5, you don't need to use `list`; the `odict_items` view that `.items()` returns implements the `__reversed__` magic method, so `reverse` can produce a reverse iterator directly without listifying.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse what it gives you:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict
>>> Foo = namedtuple('Foo', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> Foo(1, 2, 3)._asdict()
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>> OrderedDict(reversed(Foo(1, 2, 3)._asdict().items()))
OrderedDict([('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 1)])
```

If you only need to iterate it in reversed order, not actually make a new `OrderedDict`, you can just do:

```
for k, v in reversed(somenamedtuple._asdict().items()):
```

and avoid potentially large temporaries entirely.

Comment: Note: The ability to iterate views of `OrderedDict` in reverse directly was added in Python 3.5. If you're supporting older versions, you'll need to `list`ify the items view before reversing it, which sadly necessitates a temporary.

Answer (score -1):

Inorder to get a descending ordered dictionary we can use operator package which will do job easier.

For example:

```
import operator
d = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
print('Original dictionary : ',d)
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
print('Dictionary in ascending order by value : ',sorted_d)
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(),     
key=operator.itemgetter(0),reverse=True)
print('Dictionary in descending order by value : ',sorted_d)
```

Comment: This does not create an `OrderedDict` that is in the reverse order. It doesn't created a `dict` at all...

Comment: This is about the results from a `namedtuple`'s `_asdict()` method, where the results are considered sorted in ascending order already. All that's needed is reversal, not a resort based on the keys.